# Invalid admin login and logout urls when django-cms app is not mounted on root

Tags: django, django-admin, mod-wsgi, django-cms

I'm using ModWsgi for deploying my app. I have a WSGIScriptAlias which points to my cms project.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /cmsapp "/home/hari/dev/cmsproj/apache/django.wsgi"
```

I also have USE_I18N set to True in my settings, and I'm using django-cms' multilingual middleware.

I can access the admin login page via `http://localhost/cmsapp/admin/`. After I submit my credentials, I get a 404 as `http://localhost/en/admin/` page is reached. Ideally I should visit `http://localhost/cmsapp/en/admin/` - trying to visit this URL manually takes me to the admin panel.

Similarly, when I'm trying to logout from the admin panel, I get redirected to `http://localhost/en/cmsapp/admin/logout/`. If I remove 'en', I'm successfully logged out.

This is really strange. I feel that for these URLs, it appends language code after domain name, instead of appending it at the actual root. other relative URLs like `http://localhost/cmsapp/en/admin/cms/page/` and `http://localhost/cmsapp/en/admin/auth/user/` work perfectly.

Any suggestions? Are there any settings I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Set LOGIN_URL and LOGOUT_URL in settings file.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/

For whatever reason, these don't take into consideration mount point of application and it has to be added into front of those settings.